# how do i generate a valid upc?

Tags: .net, python, excel, barcode

does anyone know if it is possible to generate a valid upc?

if so, how? is it possible to do it in excel / python / .net?

the platform does not matter to me

Comment: This link will answer your question hands down nothing left to guess; http://www.cummingsdesign.com/bar_codes101_UCC_App.htm

Answer (score 2):

This should help: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Product_Code

It explains what all the digits are for (including the check digit).

Answer (score 1):

How about this? http://www.codeproject.com/KB/graphics/upc_a_barcode.aspx